# Use boolean attribute helper methods when extending from Virtus.model on the fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, boolean, virtus

Let's say I have a Virtus model `User` with a boolean attribute `active`:

```
class User
  include Virtus.model 
  attribute :active, Boolean, default: false, lazy: true
end
```

Then I could user a helper method `active?`:

```
User.new.active? # => false
User.new(active: true).active? # => true
```

But when I try to `extend` from `Virtus.model` and define a boolean attribute on the fly:

```
class User; end
user = User.new
user.extend(Virtus.model)
user.attribute(:active, Axiom::Types::Boolean, default: false, lazy: true)
user.active = true
```

and use a helper method `active?` I get a `NoMethodError` kinda exception.

```
user.active? # => NoMethodError: undefined method `active?' for
```

Is there any possibility of using helper methods in this situation?

Comment: is `user.active` is also giving error? I mean without `?`

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon, no `user.active` works just fine. It is just that using `active?` looks a lot more distinct in that way and doesn't differ from other boolean logic checks in the application.

Comment: I see, what's the full error btw? `undefined method `active?' for.....?`

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon the name of the instance object (`NoMethodError: undefined method \`active?' for #<User:0x007fb18fc59cc8>`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably there is another gem in your project that **defines a top-level `Boolean` class** and it clashes with the Boolean attribute methods. Mongoid, for example, is [known](https://github.com/solnic/virtus/issues/234) to do that. In such case, the [Virtus README suggests](https://github.com/solnic/virtus#important-note-about-boolean-type) using the `Axiom::Types::Boolean` type of the attribute instead.

However, when I tried this, it didn't help. I believe the README is actually wrong, the correct type being noted in the [Issue #234 comment](https://github.com/solnic/virtus/issues/234#issuecomment-34128292): **`Virtus::Attribute::Boolean`**.

A complete working example:

```
class User; end
user = User.new
user.extend(Virtus.model)
user.attribute(:active, 
               Virtus::Attribute::Boolean,   # <- note the type
               default: false, lazy: true)
user.active = true
user.active?
#=> true
```